# Data loading incorrectly with JavaScript/Laravel

Tags: javascript, php

At the moment I am loading a list of products but I want to restrict it to the first 10 so that I can then use the Load More button to show the rest a few at a time. Unfortunately it seems to be loading all of the products instead of a select few.

```
  <div id="products-grid" class="ui grid stackable three column">
    @foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="eight wide tablet five wide computer column" key="{{ $product->id }}">
      <div class="ui fluid card single-product">
        <a href="{{ url('brands/'.$product->brandslug.'/'.$product->slug)}}" class="image">
          @if($product->product_img != 'null')
          <img src="{{ url('/images/'.$product->product_img)}}" title="{{ $product->name }}" alt="{{ $product->name }}">
          @else
          @endif
        </a>
        <div class="product-title content">
          <a href="{{ url('brands/'.$product->brandslug.'/'.$product->slug)}}" class="title">
            <h5 class="fix-title">{{ $product->name }}</h5>
            <div class="fix-subtitle">From <a href="{{ url('/brands/'.$product->brandslug)}}">{{ $product->brandname }}</a></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <a href="{{ url('/brands/'.$product->brandslug.'/'.$product->slug)}}">
            <button class="grey ui button centered fluid">View Product</button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

Above is the product grid I have that displays the relative products.

```
if(count($products)>10)
  <div class="loadmore" id="load_more">
    <button class="ui inverted button">
      Load More
    </button>
  </div>
  @endif
```

This basically displays the button if there are more than 10 products on a particular page.

```
@section('script')
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#products-grid").slice(0, 8).show();
        if ($("#products-grid:hidden").length != 0) {
            $("#load_more").show();
        }
        $("#load_more").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#products-grid:hidden").slice(0, 6).slideDown();
            if ($("#products-grid:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#load_more").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

This is the script that is meant to hide some of the displayed products so that when I click Load More, it displays the others 6 or 7 at a time until there are no products left to show. This partially works as the button fades out when there are no products left to show (as it should do). The issue is it loads everything so I'm not sure why the javascript code isn't working as it should do?

Comment: u should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152994/laravel-load-more-data-from-controller-into-view

Comment: AFAICT you are intentionally loading all products initially, then want to progressively display new batches (that are already on the page) with JS, is that right?  So initially, all but the first 10 should be hidden, but I don't see anything in your code that does that?  Note that a more typical approach would be to only load 10 at a time from the server, then have the button click make an AJAX call to load another 10 and display them.  This might scale better if you have a large number of products, as the initial page load doesn't have to load and hide 90% of your products.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes that is correct. That is what I want to do although I'm not sure how to initially hide everything but the first 10 products to begin with? I thought the slice() method should have done that but obviously hasn't

Comment: Well, think it through out loud.  Inside your `@foreach` loop showing products, you need to know how many products you've shown.  So you'll need a counter.  Then you need to know when the counter hits 10, and after that, any other products left need to be hidden.  So you'd do that with some CSS, eg some CSS class that uses `hidden` (which your JS is going to remove when needed). Have a go! :-)

Comment: u can try with vuejs component u can do this easly

Comment: @KamleshPaul you can also do it easily without changing the stack at all.  Adding a whole new technology for ... no real reason? ... is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i think laravel has built in vuejs .?

Comment: Is OP using it?

Comment: @LukeF How did you go?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Solved it but didn't use this particular solution. Used Semantic UI Pagination to solve it.